# Cmake error: "Found unsuitable version"

Tags: 14.04, package-management, cuda, opencv, cmake

I have two versions of CUDA installed: 7.0 and 7.5. These are located at `/usr/local/cuda-7.0` and `/usr/local/cuda-7.5` respectively. I also have a symbolic link at `/usr/local/cuda` which points to `/usr/local/cuda-7.5`. I also have OpenCV 3.0 installed, which I compiled from source.

In my C++ project, my `CMakeLists.txt` file contains the line `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`. However, when running `cmake`, I get the following error:

```
Trying to find version: 7.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "7.5", but required is exact
  version "7.0" (found /usr/local/cuda)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:372 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:855 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:49 (find_package)
  /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:274 (find_host_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

I am very confused about what this is trying to tell me. Is it that OpenCV was compiled with CUDA 7.0, and so when I run `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`, it also tries to find CUDA 7.0, but it can only find CUDA 7.5? If this is the case, then why can it not find CUDA 7.0, given that I have this installed? Or is it to do with the symbolic link? Or perhaps `FindCUDA.cmake`?

Thanks for any help!